# Windows 7: How to modify what program opens a batch file?

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I remember in Windows XP where you could edit file associations to not only change what program would open certain files, but edit individual items in a file's right-click context menu.  You could also edit command line options if you wanted.

I'd like to do this with batch files so that I can change the Edit option to open the batch file with Notepad2.  Double-clicking would still execute the Open command so the batch file executes as normal.

It appears that this advanced functionality in Windows 7 has been removed and replaced by feature that simply allows you to change what program a file opens with.  Any way I can get a batch file to open for edit in a text editor of my choice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The association can be found in the Windows registry

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command

default data is

%SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1

You could change the Data target to your program of choice.

[image]

.

[I used this program to find it](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)

.

Comment: Awesome!  It worked.  I didn't even have to restart.  Thanks, mate.

Comment: Maybe %1 should be quoted in case the batch filename contains spaces. i.e. "%1"